# How to use a $variable in `ls` command?

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu-16.04, ls

I'm having problems passing a variable called `$discogs` to the `ls` command in my script.

When I'm not running the script I can echo the variable and run the command properly in the shell, however in the script it generates an error.

Here is my code:

```sh
echo "I will search for the Artist ID Number and return the Artist Name"
read id
cat file--2020-04-26.xml | grep -A 1  '<artist id="'$id'">' | tail -n 1 |  cut -c 9- | rev | cut -c 8- | rev
artist=$(cat file--2020-04-26.xml | grep -A 1  '<artist id="'$id'">' | tail -n 1 |  cut -c 9- | rev | cut -c 8- | rev)
discogs=$(curl --silent  https://athena.example.com/discogs/get_discogs_id.php?Artist="'$artist'")
echo $artist
echo Discogs ID:
echo $discogs
ls -l /root/athena/scrape/icons/png/"'*'$discogs'*'"
ls -l /root/athena/scrape/icons/png/"*${discogs}*"
```

Errors:

```sh
ls: cannot access '/root/athena/scrape/icons/png/'\''*'\'''$'\r\n\r\n\r\n''1103159'\''*'\''': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access '/root/athena/scrape/icons/png/*'$'\r\n\r\n\r\n''1103159*': No such file or directory
```

Comment: the `\r` means windows line endings aka carriage returns.

Comment: Thanks, although how can I use the variable properly in the command?

Comment: You should remove single quotes around * sign and to check and remove newlines (cr/lf) from the result  of curl command.

Comment: I've tried that and I'm still having problems.
i can echo $discogs and i can see the variable - it's only a number.

Comment: What is the output of `od -An -tx1 <<< "$discogs"` ?

Comment: 31 31 30 33 31 35 39 0a

Comment: the non octal output is 1103159

Comment: Last byte in od output 0a is linefeed character.

Comment: @user2179760 Is that the output from the `od ...` command *in the script*, or when you set `discogs` manually? Based on the error output, I'd expect the script version of the variable to give "0d  0a  0d  0a  0d  0a  31  31  30  33  31  35  39  0a". BTW, `echo $discogs` is *not* a useful way to see what the variable contains, since it won't show invisible characters (apparently the problem here), and without double-quotes around the variable it'll also do weird things with any whitespace and/or wildcards in the variable's value.

Comment: That is the output from the `od ...` after the curl command in the script (variable `$discogs`).  There appears to be a bug in the script where the last byte '0a' is a linefeed character - this would being created by the php script (which is apparently the problem)

Comment: I tried with adding `|  tr -d '\n'`at the end of my curl command - except I'm still getting new line characters. `https://athena.example.com/discogs/get_discogs_id.php?Artist="$artist" |  tr -d '\n')`

Answer (score 0):

Try passing your `curl` result through `| tr -d '[:space:]'`.